# Android: Intent Extras only get caught when app fully force closed

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app I have a service that shows a Notifications, where when clicked does open an Fragment Activity intent with Extras..

Those Extras I have handled in the OnRusume to assign to a string

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        String Number = null;
        try{
        Number = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("callNumber");
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Extra allocation", e.toString());
        }
}
```

The problem is that, lets say I minimize the app (click Home button), then I click on notification, but no extras are assigned, then I force close the app (Hold Home button and Slide away the app) and click the same exact notification, but this time with extras assigned..
What is a possible cause of this, and how to be solved?

Comment: what is the launch mode of the activity? if it is already opened maybe you are just bringing it back to front from the notification.

Comment: It is being brought back to front, but I have test the OnResume by showing a Log.i("Fragment", "RESUMED") and apparently the OnResume runs everytime the app is brought to front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to solve the problem, I'm not sure why its caused, but apparently an Activity is unable to receive any extras from intent when its brought back to front, but rather when only created entirely.
Solved by setting
the Activity to

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

check the flow of activity on the link above, u might want to implement the same thing somewhere as well, my guess being, on Onpause()